# Configure By-Product BoM to trigger after set amount of production

Tags: odoo, production

Working with Odoo Online (v10 for local)

We have a specific production workflow, whereas the production only creates a by-product whenever X amount of the resource is used up. The By-Product cannot be used to produce the originally ordered product.

For example;

- Resource is 1.10m long
- Produced good is 0.25m long
- This means after 4 times production, the rest resource will be 0.10m

Triggering the by-product at a prefixed amount of production seems essential, as using the solution to break the 0.10m in 0.025m per unit isn't feasible. Then the by-product will be registered smaller than the actual size.

Idea - A being the resource

1xA = 40xB + 1xC

1xA = 20xD + 1xD

1xA = 10xF + 1xG